# Rails / ActiveRecord - strategy for getting validations with queries to work with non-persisted objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is sort of an abstract question, but here goes. I have a Child class with a parent and siblings:

```
class Child
  belongs_to :parent

  validate do
    if !val_matches_sister_val
      # do something
    end
  end

  def val_matches_sister_val
    val == parent.other_children.find_by(name: search_name)&.val
  end
end

class Parent
  has_many :children
  has_many :other_children
end

class OtherChild
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I have a validation in Child that needs to compare a value from one of the parent's other_children, and I perform the search by name using the find_by query.

This works fine as long as the records are persisted because find_by works as expected. But if I just build them:

```
parent = Parent.new

parent.other_children.build

child = Child.new(parent: parent)
```

The instance of child would be invalid because find_by would return nil. I'm trying to run tests in RSpec without persisting everything to the database (for performance), and this is failing. I know I can just persist the records, but I wonder if there's another way.

I can think of a couple solutions to this problem, but they all seem clunky:

- make the method iterate through all of the other_children records in memory
- only create objects, but I'm running this in RSpec and creation is slower than building and unnecessary for my test
- make the method aware of persistence (yuck)

Is there a good solution to this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: `find_by` is an Active Record method that finds something in the database -- no way around that.  Since you are testing this functionality -- probably worth the price to put something in the database -- though fixtures might be be a better answer in this case.  You could mock out find_by to return the desired object and assume that find_by will work as advertised in the real code.

Comment: Yeah, the performance penalty is minor for my use case, but I know a ton of database use can get pretty gnarly with large test suites. I was just curious if the Rails community had come up with some solution since this seems like it wouldn't be particularly rare.